# Google Chrome lets me know when a video is in full screen

Tags: google-chrome, youtube

I just updated Google Chrome `16.0.912.77 m` and when I watch [YouTube](http://youtube.com) videos, and make them full screen, Chrome wants to confirm with me that its OK to have YouTube.com in full screen.

How do I prevent Chrome from asking me this for any site?

Comment: I think this is a flash thing, not something that can really be controlled by chrome as such

Comment: Agreed. But version 16 is also a bit old. If you take a look at the Wiki page ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Chrome ), the newest stable is 17.0.963.56

Comment: @wizlog - There is no way you "just" updated to version 16 of Chrome, version 17 has been out for weeks, update your installation and then return when you can provide more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to prevent this - this message is by design to stop malicious webpages.

If this was not the case, a malicious website could become fullscreen and show you a picture of Google Chrome with the URL bar and HTTPs logo showing you that you're securely talking to bankofamerica.com, but with the webpage secretly sending your login credentials to joes-malware-site.com.

Comment: I have the latest version of Chrome and it does not give me this prompt.